# Qt6.4: CMAKE QML project doesn't compile

Tags: multithreading, qt, cmake, qt6

I just updated to Qt6.4.2 today, but the newly created QML project with CMAKE cannot compile.

**Qt Version**:

> Qt Creator 10.0.0
>
> Based on Qt 6.4.2 (MSVC 2019, x86_64)
>
> Built on Mar 28 2023 10:37:51
>
> Built on Mar 28 2023 10:37:51

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(untitled7 VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup()

qt_add_executable(appuntitled7
    main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(appuntitled7
    URI untitled7
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES Main.qml
)

set_target_properties(appuntitled7 PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(appuntitled7
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
)

install(TARGETS appuntitled7
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

**The errors are**:

```
Running E:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin\cmake.exe -S C:/Users/xxx/Documents/untitled7 -B C:/Users/xxx/Documents/build-untitled7-Desktop_Qt_6_4_3_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug in C:\Users\xxx\Documents\build-untitled7-Desktop_Qt_6_4_3_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  project could not find requested file:

    C:/Users/xxx/Documents/build-untitled7-Desktop_Qt_6_4_3_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug/.qtc/package-manager/auto-setup.cmake


CMake Error at E:/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindThreads.cmake:66 (message):
  FindThreads only works if either C or CXX language is enabled
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  E:/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47 (find_package)
  E:/Qt/6.4.3/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPublicDependencyHelpers.cmake:33 (find_dependency)
  E:/Qt/6.4.3/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Dependencies.cmake:24 (_qt_internal_find_third_party_dependencies)
  E:/Qt/6.4.3/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake:112 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    E:/Qt/6.4.3/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake

  but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake process exited with exit code 1.

Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

[image]

I tried to add "find_package(THREADS REQUIRED)" to the CMakeLists.txt, but it doesn't work.

And I tried to create a widget project with *.pro file, it compiles without any issue.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: I tried using your `CMakeLists.txt` file on my end, I had to replace `Qt6 6.4` with `Qt6 6.5.0` because that's the version I have installed, and it worked fine, so try using `Qt6 6.4.3`(The Qt version that you seem to be using), if that does not work, the problem is most likely with your Qt installation.

Comment: Thanks. I update the Qt to Qt6.5 today, but it still doesn't work. It seems an issue with just my environment.